# How can I update statistics in SQL Server 2012 without using sp_updatestats?

Tags: sql-server

I have read that if I use the command:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

That this creates statistics based on an estimated 20,000 rows per table. I am not sure what this means as I have many tables with less than 20 rows.

Can someone give me advice on if there's another more accurate way to update statistics that will not involve my entering a command for every table.

Comment: Be more careful with sources for information. Check facts by reading authoritative sources .This question is based on a false assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to collect statistics other way then Microsoft recommends ?

> more accurate way to update statistics that will not involve my
>   entering a command for every table

This command update statistics for all tables in the current database and you don't need to enter this command for every table in the database:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats;
```

Also you can use [UPDATE STATISTICS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) command. I don't know the advantages of UPDATE STATISTiCS over sp_updatestats and I think you can use both of them.

It is a good way to collect actual statistics for your data, but be aware that it can be heavy operation and require many server resources.  If it is possible I recommens to collect statistics when most of the users don't work with the data.

Other maintenence solution (like rebuild and reorganize indexes) you can find [in this post](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Someone downvoted your answer but I have upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Following query show list of table that need to update statistics. you can use cursor for result of this query and update statistics of each table that need to update statistics.

```
SELECT SchemaName, ObjectName, StatisticName, [RowCount], UpdatedCount
FROM (
    SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS SchemaName,
        OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) AS ObjectName,
        s.Name AS StatisticName,
        rows AS [RowCount],
        modification_counter AS UpdatedCount,
        modification_counter/rows * 100 AS UpdatePercent,
        rows * -0.00001846153+19.538461 AS threshold
    FROM sys.stats  s
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id, s.stats_id) b
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = s.object_id
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id,'IsUserTable')=1
    )z
WHERE z.UpdatePercent > 20
    OR (z.[RowCount]>=25000 AND z.[RowCount]<=1000000 AND z.UpdatePercent>2 AND z.UpdatePercent > z.threshold)
    OR (z.[RowCount]>1000000 AND z.[RowCount]<=10000000 AND z.UpdatePercent>1)
    OR (z.[RowCount]>10000000 AND z.[RowCount]<=20000000 AND z.UpdatePercent>0.5)
    OR (z.[RowCount]>20000000 AND z.[RowCount]<=30000000 AND z.UpdatePercent>0.25)
ORDER BY z.UpdatePercent
```

When you set `Auto Update Statistics` (`ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON`), sql server update automatically statistics of your table when updated row amount was 20% of count rows. it's seem good in first glance. But 20% of small table is very different with 20% of a large table. In other word if your table have 100 rows, each time that update 20 rows affected, sql server update statistics of your table automatically but if your table have 100,000,000 rows, each time update of 20,000,000 rows affected, sql server automatically update statistic of this table and this update rows need very time to affected. It seem that small table need to update statistics when Updated rows count was 20% of total rows and larg table need to update statistics when updated rows count was 1% of total rows. In my query I show list of table that need to updated statistics according to table rows count and update rows count.